# how to make a logical condition for reward

Tags: if-statement

i made a referral system , and i want to make when the referral reach level 5 to give money to the user who referred him .
i have something like this :

```
$sql   = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users_ref` WHERE userid='$user[id]'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)
if (get_refuser_level($row['userref'] > 4) {
            $update = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money=money+$newmoney WHERE id='$user[id]'");
}
```

but if i made like this , i recive money every time wen i press F5 , it is possible to make this condition to run only one time or i need to make with db ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best approach would be to introduce a new boolean field storing whether the money is paid or not.

Comment: thank you for reply , if i made like you say , wen the ref is level 5 , i recive money every time wen i press f5 , only if the user reach level 6 , i stop to get money , i need to put a new boolean , i will do this and i come back with a answer

Comment: Oh yes.. I'm really sorry. I'll edit the answer so that it won't mislead others.

Comment: keep calm , we are humans , we all made mistakes :)) , i wait for another answer , if is possible only with php , if not , i will make with a new boolean field in sql